# Distinguishing between two similar usb devices

Tags: linux, usb, udev

This is asked many a times before, but I haven't found any workable solution for my case. In my case, I have got two FTDI based USB <-> Serial converters from which I could not find any distinguishing feature to include in `udev` rules that I intend to write in order to identify them with a persistent name. The outputs of:

`udevadm info --attribute-walk --path=/sys/bus/usb-serial/devices/ttyUSB0`

```
looking at device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0/ttyUSB0':
    KERNEL=="ttyUSB0"
    SUBSYSTEM=="usb-serial"
    DRIVER=="ftdi_sio"
    ATTR{port_number}=="0"
    ATTR{latency_timer}=="1"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0':
    KERNELS=="3-1:1.0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="ftdi_sio"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceClass}=="ff"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceSubClass}=="ff"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceProtocol}=="ff"
    ATTRS{bNumEndpoints}=="02"
    ATTRS{supports_autosuspend}=="1"
    ATTRS{bAlternateSetting}==" 0"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceNumber}=="00"
    ATTRS{interface}=="USB <-> Serial"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-1':
    KERNELS=="3-1"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="00"
    ATTRS{devpath}=="1"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="0403"
    ATTRS{speed}=="12"
    ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 1"
    ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="8"
    ATTRS{busnum}=="3"
    ATTRS{devnum}=="21"
    ATTRS{configuration}==""
    ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="90mA"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="80"
    ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
    ATTRS{maxchild}=="0"
    ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0400"
    ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
    ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
    ATTRS{version}==" 1.10"
    ATTRS{urbnum}=="11"
    ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
    ATTRS{manufacturer}=="FTDI"
    ATTRS{removable}=="removable"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="6001"
    ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{product}=="USB <-> Serial"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3':
    KERNELS=="usb3"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="01"
    ATTRS{devpath}=="0"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="1d6b"
    ATTRS{speed}=="480"
    ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 1"
    ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="64"
    ATTRS{authorized_default}=="1"
    ATTRS{busnum}=="3"
    ATTRS{devnum}=="1"
    ATTRS{configuration}==""
    ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="0mA"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="e0"
    ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
    ATTRS{maxchild}=="4"
    ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0313"
    ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
    ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
    ATTRS{serial}=="0000:00:14.0"
    ATTRS{version}==" 2.00"
    ATTRS{urbnum}=="383"
    ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
    ATTRS{manufacturer}=="Linux 3.13.0-32-generic xhci_hcd"
    ATTRS{removable}=="unknown"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="0002"
    ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="09"
    ATTRS{product}=="xHCI Host Controller"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0':
    KERNELS=="0000:00:14.0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="pci"
    DRIVERS=="xhci_hcd"
    ATTRS{irq}=="40"
    ATTRS{subsystem_vendor}=="0x17aa"
    ATTRS{broken_parity_status}=="0"
    ATTRS{class}=="0x0c0330"
    ATTRS{enabled}=="1"
    ATTRS{consistent_dma_mask_bits}=="64"
    ATTRS{dma_mask_bits}=="64"
    ATTRS{local_cpus}=="ff"
    ATTRS{device}=="0x1e31"
    ATTRS{msi_bus}==""
    ATTRS{local_cpulist}=="0-7"
    ATTRS{vendor}=="0x8086"
    ATTRS{subsystem_device}=="0x3977"
    ATTRS{d3cold_allowed}=="1"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00':
    KERNELS=="pci0000:00"
    SUBSYSTEMS==""
    DRIVERS==""
```

and same when done for ttyUSB1:

`udevadm info --attribute-walk --path=/sys/bus/usb-serial/devices/ttyUSB0`

```
looking at device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.0/ttyUSB1':
    KERNEL=="ttyUSB1"
    SUBSYSTEM=="usb-serial"
    DRIVER=="ftdi_sio"
    ATTR{port_number}=="0"
    ATTR{latency_timer}=="1"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.0':
    KERNELS=="3-2:1.0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="ftdi_sio"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceClass}=="ff"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceSubClass}=="ff"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceProtocol}=="ff"
    ATTRS{bNumEndpoints}=="02"
    ATTRS{supports_autosuspend}=="1"
    ATTRS{bAlternateSetting}==" 0"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceNumber}=="00"
    ATTRS{interface}=="USB <-> Serial"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-2':
    KERNELS=="3-2"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="00"
    ATTRS{devpath}=="2"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="0403"
    ATTRS{speed}=="12"
    ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 1"
    ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="8"
    ATTRS{busnum}=="3"
    ATTRS{devnum}=="22"
    ATTRS{configuration}==""
    ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="90mA"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="80"
    ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
    ATTRS{maxchild}=="0"
    ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0400"
    ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
    ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
    ATTRS{version}==" 1.10"
    ATTRS{urbnum}=="11"
    ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
    ATTRS{manufacturer}=="FTDI"
    ATTRS{removable}=="removable"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="6001"
    ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{product}=="USB <-> Serial"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3':
    KERNELS=="usb3"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="01"
    ATTRS{devpath}=="0"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="1d6b"
    ATTRS{speed}=="480"
    ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 1"
    ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="64"
    ATTRS{authorized_default}=="1"
    ATTRS{busnum}=="3"
    ATTRS{devnum}=="1"
    ATTRS{configuration}==""
    ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="0mA"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="e0"
    ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
    ATTRS{maxchild}=="4"
    ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0313"
    ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
    ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
    ATTRS{serial}=="0000:00:14.0"
    ATTRS{version}==" 2.00"
    ATTRS{urbnum}=="383"
    ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
    ATTRS{manufacturer}=="Linux 3.13.0-32-generic xhci_hcd"
    ATTRS{removable}=="unknown"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="0002"
    ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="09"
    ATTRS{product}=="xHCI Host Controller"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0':
    KERNELS=="0000:00:14.0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="pci"
    DRIVERS=="xhci_hcd"
    ATTRS{irq}=="40"
    ATTRS{subsystem_vendor}=="0x17aa"
    ATTRS{broken_parity_status}=="0"
    ATTRS{class}=="0x0c0330"
    ATTRS{enabled}=="1"
    ATTRS{consistent_dma_mask_bits}=="64"
    ATTRS{dma_mask_bits}=="64"
    ATTRS{local_cpus}=="ff"
    ATTRS{device}=="0x1e31"
    ATTRS{msi_bus}==""
    ATTRS{local_cpulist}=="0-7"
    ATTRS{vendor}=="0x8086"
    ATTRS{subsystem_device}=="0x3977"
    ATTRS{d3cold_allowed}=="1"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00':
    KERNELS=="pci0000:00"
    SUBSYSTEMS==""
    DRIVERS==""
```

I tried implementing the first solution @ [How to distinguish between identical USB-to-serial adapters?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49910/how-to-distinguish-between-identical-usb-to-serial-adapters) by assigning KERNELS=="3-1" to ttyUSB0 and KERNELS=="3-2" to ttyUSB1, but it is not persistent and changes everytime I re-connect the devices. Moreover `ATTRS{devnum}` also keeps changing everytime, but it can be noted that they are always in sequence. So, can I use them to fix device names? I am not sure that same device will always be initialized with smaller or larger `devnum`. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Moved to [Distinguishing between two similar usb devices](http://askubuntu.com/questions/698990/distinguishing-between-two-similar-usb-devices)

Answer (score 0):

The `KERNELS` attribute is the bus path for the device and should be consistent as long as they are always plugged into the same port (and if that port is on a hub the hub is plugged into the same port, etc). As the two devices are identical there is no other way to distinguish them than by the port they are connected to.

Comment: Yes, did something like this only by taking `ENV{ID_PATH}` as distinguishing param since devices would stay connected to same ports as you rightly pointed out. The issue has been solved as I moved to askUbuntu.